# Using JQuery to change element ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to change an element ID using jquery for an A/B test.

From what ive seen, it should go something like this:

`$('#tag').attr('oldId','newId');`

But so far, no dice - any ideas?

*I've looked through the responses and i think i had the wrong end of the stick! I was assuming the current / old id had to be placed where ive labelled 'oldId', rather than id, followed by the replacement - silly mistake, thanks for all the help :)

Comment: `$('#oldID').attr('ID','newId');`

Comment: `tag.id = "newId";` works on all HTML5 compiliant browsers

Comment: @A.Wolff until you have a variable called `tag` in your local scope

Comment: `tag` is already an id what is your `oldId` then?

Comment: @Alnitak ya or element(s) with "tag" as `name` attribute

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to use the proper signature of `.attr('attributeName','value')`,

```
$('#tag').attr("id","newId")
```

Comment: Bear in mind that (in some cases, I'm not sure about this one) updating the attribute doesn't necessarily update the property; it might be better/safer to use `prop('id', 'newId')`.

Comment: @DavidThomas `id` isn't one of those cases

Comment: @DavidThomas I heard that, usage of `.attr()` will not be encouraged while setting operational properties of a DOM element like disabled,checked, etc.. I think setting ID by using .attr() wont harm anything. Am i right??

Comment: This is not what the OP is trying to do, OP has `tag` as id and want to change just attribute oldId to newId, seems to me OP is confusing us...

Comment: So Alnitak says (and I'm happy to believe him in this), so it should be safe. I'd still, personally, choose `prop()` but I've got no argument in its favour, it's just a personal choice.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal The way, OP made the question is confusing. But this is what he is trying to do. :)

Comment: Then replace `#tag` with `#oldId`

Comment: @DavidThomas AIUI, in input element's "value / checked" style properties this can be an issue, because the attribute reflects what was in the loaded HTML (i.e. the initial state) but the property reflects the _current_ state of the element.  In most other cases the two are interchangeable.  Another exception is `<a href>` or `<img src>` where the equivalent property will be an absolute URL even if the HTML source attribute was relative.

Comment: Important to note that if you are tracking actions by ID, you will need to use: $(document).on('click', 'XXXX', function() { - otherwise the DOM will have the original ID saved in its place.  For me, I was updating the ID on a "next" button and it always saw my ID as the original when the page was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** The right syntax is: `$("#myId").attr("id", "mySecondId")`

Comment: Are you absolutely sure of that?

Comment: I hear that the first time

Comment: My bad, it's totally possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#tag').attr('id','newId');
```

This will change `id` of element

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoj/6ezog4ey/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#tag').attr('id','newId');
```

Answer (score 0):

If `oldId` really is the element's current ID, then instead of `#tag` you just need:

```
$('#oldId').attr('id', 'newId');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
**$('#oldID').attr('id','newID');**
you have to pass attrbuteName as first argument and attributeValue as second argument.

Answer (score 0):

$("#tag"), here "tag" is your id.
line2: $("#tag").attr("id","newId");
You should not pass "tag" as your first param to attr.
You must tell which attribute you want to set, i.e "id", followed by a value.
In a simpler language, line2 attr function takes a key and its value to be set.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guy, ended up using:

$('#tag').attr("id","newId")

with 'id' as 'id' and not current id tag